# ParNew GC messages

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Follwoing are ParNew GC messages output during the course of application execution:

```
150.101: [GC 150.101: [ParNew: 5825408K->1165056K(5825408K), 6.2067219 secs] 16772901K->14058101K(19806464K), 6.2068006 secs] [Times: user=23.91 sys=5.36, real=6.21 secs]
157.102: [GC 157.102: [ParNew: 5825408K->5825408K(5825408K), 0.0000290 secs]157.102: [Tenured: 12893045K->13981055K(13981056K), 75.5013636 secs] 18718453K->15612302K(19806464K), [Perm : 27061K->27021K(131072K)], 75.5015492 secs] [Times:user=73.91 sys=1.65, real=75.50 secs]
```

What is the meaning of following messages ?

```
5825408K->1165056K(5825408K)
16772901K->14058101K(19806464K)
12893045K->13981055K(13981056K)
18718453K->15612302K(19806464K)
27061K->27021K(131072K)
```

When the application ended, it printed:

```
Heap

 par new generation   total 5825408K, used 2831058K [0xfffffd7ac0000000, 0xfffffd7c6aaa0000, 0xfffffd7c6aaa0000)
  eden space 4660352K,  60% used [0xfffffd7ac0000000, 0xfffffd7b6ccb4a10, 0xfffffd7bdc720000)
  from space 1165056K,   0% used [0xfffffd7bdc720000, 0xfffffd7bdc720000, 0xfffffd7c238e0000)
  to   space 1165056K,   0% used [0xfffffd7c238e0000, 0xfffffd7c238e0000, 0xfffffd7c6aaa0000)
 tenured generation   total 13981056K, used 13981055K [0xfffffd7c6aaa0000, 0xfffffd7fc0000000, 0xfffffd7fc0000000)
   the space 13981056K,  99% used [0xfffffd7c6aaa0000, 0xfffffd7fbffffff0, 0xfffffd7fc0000000, 0xfffffd7fc0000000)
 compacting perm gen  total 131072K, used 27115K [0xfffffd7fc0000000, 0xfffffd7fc8000000, 0xfffffd7fc8000000)
   the space 131072K,  20% used [0xfffffd7fc0000000, 0xfffffd7fc1a7acf0, 0xfffffd7fc1a7ae00, 0xfffffd7fc8000000)

No shared spaces configured.
```

Why the number of eden space, from space and to space do add up to "par new genration" which I assume means the young generation? It seems only one of the semi-spaces is counted

Comment: “in use before gc”->“in use after gc”(“total size”)